# Python find the projection point of a known point on an ellipse

Tags: python, projection

I need to implement this process:

Regarding the following image I know the coordinates of the red dots. I have to find the projection of the red point in ellipse, thus the purple point of the ellipse.

I have the points of the orange line and the points of the ellipse.

Is there any available algorithm to do this?[image]

Comment: Does the line always pass through origin? and center of the ellipse is always origin?

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak Yes to both!

Comment: In its current form, this is a mathematics question, not a coding question, so you may have more luck at  https://math.stackexchange.com . But you should be a bit more specific about the information you have. I assume you mean you have the equations of the orange line and the ellipse; it would help if you gave an explicit example so we know what form those equations are in.

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't have the equations but I have all the corresponding points respectively.

Comment: Could you change base (so your ellipse axes are x' and y', then the blue point has for coordinate : (x'_red,-y'_red) and then you change base again

Comment: @pwnsauce Is there any function in python that can change my base?

Comment: Ow... No, but if you have the yellow line coordinate it's fairly easy, it's juste a rotation. You'll have to calculate the angle between Yellow line and x axe. (it's seems to me here it's 45° here but it might be because it's an exemple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ellipse is symmetric about the given line, all you need is to calculate the reflection of the point about the line.

[image: equation]

Here `x1` and `y1` are the coordinates of the red point and `ax+by+c=0` is the equation of the line. `x`, `y` is the coordinate of the reflected point.

Since the line passes through origin, `c` is 0.

If you know the angle (θ) the line makes with x-axis you can calculate the value of `a` and `b` as

We know that `y = x * tan(θ)` and `a x + b y = 0` so

```
-a/b = tan(θ)
```

Taking `b = 1`, `a` becomes `-tan(θ)`

Reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013230/how-to-find-coordinates-of-reflected-point

Comment: There are 5000 possible way of solving this, but this seems to be the best. Btw, what is the purpose of the ellipse in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a right triangle with non-right vertices at the red points, then this would allow you to calculate the distance to the orange line from the projection point which will be the same length to the purple point.

Triangle construction could proceed from constructing a line (A) between the red points, finding the angle between the origin point and orange line (angle B). From there the angle between the A line and right vertex line is given by 90-(Angle B). Then the length of the chord follows.

Comment: Can you please be more explicit? Can you give a simple diagram and/or the need functions to support your solution?

Answer (score 0):

let the vector from the "center" red point *c* to the other red point *r* be **u**, and the vector from the center red point to some other point on the orange line be **v**.  We want to rotate **u** through twice the angle between **u** and **v**.  Let θ be the angle between **u** and **v**.  We can take a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) of twice θ, and multiply it by **u** to get the vector from the red "center" point *c* to the purple point *p*.  Since we know the cosine of the angle between the red-points-line and the orange line in terms of the points, we shouldn't have to take any sines or cosines of angles or anything, we can just express it all in vector [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) and such.

One can probably crunch this down to a simpler equation, but this is an algorithm that reflects "showing your work":

- Find cosine(θ) as **u** * **v** / ||**u**|| ||**v**||
- Find cosine(2θ) and sine(2θ) from cosine(θ) using the [double angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle_formulae) and [pythagorean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Pythagorean_identities) identities
- Construct the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)
- Multiply the rotation matrix by **u** to get **w**, the vector from *c* to *p*
- Add the components of **w** to the coordinates of *c* to get the coordinates of *p*

Answer (score 0):

Given that you did not specify the exact form of your equations for points and lines I will assume the following notation: The orange line goes through the origin and along a vector `[v1,v2]`, such that every point on it can be written as `a*[v1,v2]`. Given this the following approach should work:

1. find any perpendicular vector to v (I will call it n): any vector of the form `n=[-(v2*n2)/v1, n2]` with non-zero n2.
2. formulate the line through the red point (not the origin) that goes along n: `[r1,r2]+b*[-(v2*n2)/v1, n2]`describes any such point.
3. find the parameters a and b, for which these lines intersect: solve a*v1=r1-b*(v2*n2)/v1 and a*v2=r2*b*n2 for a and b .The result for b, which is what you need is given by:

   ```
   b= (v1*(r1*v1-r2*v1))/(n2*(v1^2 + v2^2))
   ```
4. the purple point will have the coordinates `[r1,r2]+2*b*[-(v2*n2)/v1, n2]` for whatever n2 you chose.